# What is the correct order to use matrices in Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotational-matrices

I have looked on several resources such as this http://antongerdelan.net/teaching/3dprog1/maths_cheat_sheet.pdf

I have found out that I am supposed to use column major ordering, the confusion comes in when I discover the answer of this question

[Why does my translation matrix needs to be transposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293469/why-does-my-translation-matrix-needs-to-be-transposed)

the answer shows a translation matrix in column major ordering but the previous resource shows a translation matrix in column major ordering and it appears to be the transpose of the one shown in this answer.

I understand that the matrix in this answer is correct because I have tried it out and my transformation works. what I am trying to find is the column major scale, rotation and perspective matrices also written in this c++ array style notation rather that the one in the first resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a careful reading of

[Why does my translation matrix needs to be transposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293469/why-does-my-translation-matrix-needs-to-be-transposed)

the difference is that the first page you are looking at is showing you the *mathematical notation* for your matrices, in which each single column is arranged along a vertical line; whereas the other notation you are looking at is a sequence of characters resembling something that might occur *in your C++ code*.  There are many other differences, such as the tall square brackets in the math notation (which are impossible to reproduce exactly in C++ code, as there are no characters that span multiple lines), and the fact that there are no commas between the numbers in math notation.

But the main thing is that since the matrix is stored in column-major order, if you initialize the entries in the order in which they are stored (such as by using the notation for initializing an array from a comma-separated list), then `x`, `y`, `z`, and `1` will be the *last four entries* you will set in the matrix.  And since C++ is always parsed as a linear string reading left to right (the parser doesn't care what number happens to be directly under what other number when you look at the listing), if you happen to format a list of 16 values in 4 rows of 4 values each, the last four values in the list are the ones on the last *row* of your format.

Comment: I'm not so sure your last sentence is accurate. The way OpenGL lays out column-major matrices in memory, each sequential memory location represents either 1 row *down* from the previous location or if the previous location already represented the last row in the matrix, then the first row of the next column to the *right*. The last 4 values in a list of floats would, therefore, be the last ***column*** of an Nx4 column-major matrix.

Comment: In short, the confusion arises because a _matrix_ (either the mathematical kind, or its representation in memory on a computer) is a very different thing from a _C++ source code listing_. My last sentence refers to something in the format of C++ source code.